# Smart Contract Design: Escrow/Controller contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, interfaces

How would I go about creating follow: 
 Escrow/Controller contract A which is capable of accepting ERC20tokens from contract B, and ETH from party C and do a swap when certain conditions are met.

This same contract A should also be able to receive ERC20tokens from contract D and ETH from contract E and do a swap when certain conditions are met.

**The catch/relevancy of the question is**, how to design contract A to be able to handle ERC20token inputs of different kinds e.g. Walton(WTC) & FUSION(FSN) ERC20 tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where interfaces come in. That's great, because ERC-20 is actually an interface! I'll give you an example below. As you can see, the `TokenSwapper` doesn't even need to know about `TokenA` and `TokenB`, just that they implement the `ERC20` interface.

Oh and before you start developing, you should first make yourself familiar with the basics of the ERC20 interface. [Read this wiki](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

/* Declaring the ERC20 interface. This tells
   other contracts how to handle ERC-20 tokens */
interface ERC20 {
    function allowance(address owner, address spender)
    external view returns (uint256);

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value)
    external returns (bool);

    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external returns (bool);

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address who) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
}


/* a simple base ERC token contract for testing */
/* DO NOT USE FOR PRODUCTION AS IT IS NOT SAFE */
contract ERC20Token is ERC20 {
    uint256 totalSupply_;

    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;
    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return totalSupply_;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) external returns (bool) {
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);


        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;

        return true;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

      function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _value
    )
        public
        returns (bool)
    {
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_value <= balances[_from]);
        require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

        balances[_from] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;

        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(
        address _owner,
        address _spender
    )
    public
    view
    returns (uint256)
    {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }
}

/* The tokens inherit their functionality from ERC20Token */
contract TokenA is ERC20Token {
}

contract TokenB is ERC20Token {
}

contract TokenC is ERC20Token {
}
contract TokenD is ERC20Token {
}

/* DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION AS IT DOESN'T CHECK FOR UNDERFLOW/OVERFLOW */
contract TokenSwapper {
    // Keeps track of the tokens users have
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) tokenBalances_;

    function tokenBalances(address _owner, ERC20 _token) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balance = tokenBalances_[_owner][_token];
    }

    function deposit(ERC20 _token, uint256 _amount) public {
        _token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
        tokenBalances_[msg.sender][_token] += _amount;
    }

    function swap(ERC20 _fromToken, ERC20 _toToken, uint256 _amount) public {
        tokenBalances_[msg.sender][_fromToken] -= _amount;
        tokenBalances_[msg.sender][_toToken] += _amount;
    }

    function withdraw(ERC20 _token, uint256 _amount) public {
        require(tokenBalances_[msg.sender][_token] >= _amount);

        _token.transfer(msg.sender, _amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Henk, so 'TokenSwapper' can hold any type of erc20token in tokenBalances, along as address is specified? Is there no need to generate a object from the interface initially like in crowd sales? e.g. ERC20 public token; thanks for answering, interfaces has been bothering me for a while.. isn't it possible to transfer ERC20 instead of transferFrom?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Using `transfer` is not secure, as the smart contract cannot detect when it received tokens

Comment: maybe this is a stupid question, but what if the interface is named 'Token' or something else, would you still be able to use ERC20 as the input argument type for _token? in the TokenSwapper contract?

Comment: Yep, the name doesn't matter. The names of the functions, however declared in the interface, do matter.

Comment: How does TokenSwapper know that it has to use an interface if it's not inherited by the contract or specified within the contract? thanks so much for clearing my bottlenecks!